# TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

im creating a economy system for my own server, so the bot won't be in any other servers.

error:

```
 File "c:\Users\trace\Desktop\MU LFG\lfg bot\main.py", line 303, in open_account
    if str(user.id) in users :
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

code:https://paste.pythondiscord.com/4AKA

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Answer (score 0):

The error mentions that the object you are trying to iterate through, which in your case is `users`, is a boolean value. I assume that you expect `users` to be list-like (e.g., list, set) or a dictionary.

In that case, how do you set the `users` value? Let's look at your context.

```py
async def open_account(ctx):
      
    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author

    if str(user.id) in users :
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["Bank"] = 0

    with open("mb.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
```

So, `users` is set via `get_bank_data()`. And what does `get_bank_data()` return?

```py
async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mb.json","r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return True # returns a boolean value
```

So, currently `users` returns a boolean value. So, the error is expected. To fix the issue, you may want to return the `users` object being read in `get_bank_data` instead since that is currently the data you are reading.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you need to return json generated dict in the function `get_bank_data()` and then you can check if the key is in the `dict`.

The main issue is that after an `in` you need a type that is iterable like `dict` or `list` and you were returning a `bool`

```py
@client.command(aliases=['bal'])
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["Bank"]
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", color= discord.Color.random())
    em.add_field(name="Wallet Balance", value= wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name='Bank Balance', value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
        
    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author

    earnings = random.randrange(101)

    await ctx.send(f"Someone gave you {earnings} cherrio")

    users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] += earnings

    with open("mb.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

async def open_account(ctx):
      
    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author

    if str(user.id) in users :
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["Wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["Bank"] = 0

    with open("mb.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)


async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mb.json","r") as f:
        return json.load(f)
    # Note here I delete previous return
```

also you may consider to make `users` a [global variable](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_global_variables.asp)